# Solve the following (logarithmic) function for $x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, logarithms

> $(\log_{3}x)^{2} - 3\log_{3}x + 2 = 0$

We may not use many rules, so I would start by ignoring the `^(2)`, ignore `-3*` but take care of the rest. Ignore these because $factor * zero = 0$.

So I would get:

$((\log_{3}x)+1) (-\log_{3}x -2) = 0$

Now need to find two x so that one of these factors equal zero, so

$(\log_{3}x) \in \{-1, 2\}$

$\Rightarrow $  $x \in \{ 3^{-1}, 3^{2} \} =  \{ \frac{1}{3}, 9 \}$

Can I do it like that and is it correct?

I have tested it for $1/3$ and it doesn't work but it works for $9$

Comment: You mean "solve" or "resolve"

Comment: Not sure how to say it but find a or several solutions for x so the entire term equals zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should be $$\left( \log _{ 3 }{ x } -1 \right) \left( \log _{ 3 }{ x } -2 \right) =0$$
$$\log _{ 3 }{ x } =1\Rightarrow \quad x=3\\ \log _{ 3 }{ x } =2\Rightarrow x=9$$

Comment: Thank you! The rest is fine? Or there are some things than cannot be written as I did?
That was very fast by the way, you solved it in like 30 sec and posted answer same time :-)

Comment: you are welcome,no the $1/3$ is not answer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ignore the exponent or the multiplication.

In this case, set temporarily $t=\log_3x$ so the equation becomes
$$
t^2-3t+2=0
$$
which has roots $t=1$ and $t=2$. Thus you get the two equations
$$
\log_3x=1
$$
and
$$
\log_3x=2
$$
Can you finish them?

Your method would be sound, too, provided you did the decomposition right.

Comment: You are using substitution here, I'm not sure if we are allowed to do it but it's an interesting trick, good to know.
Actually, we should be allowed to do it... It's nothing unknown imo.

Comment: @kathelk It is just a shorthand for avoiding to carry around complicated symbols. A very standard and elementary technique.